# I no longer have an alignment issue, however, when I print out my X's and O's there will be a 0 next to them. Does anyone know a different solution?

Tags: python

This is what I have so far, if you have any ideas please let me know. It would mean a lot to me.

```
a_list = list(range(1, squared_input + 1))
turn = 0
Symbol_1 = "X"
Symbol_2 = "O"

while turn <= 9:
  X = 1
  while X < squared_input + 1 :
    print(str(a_list[X - 1]).zfill(2), end= "")
    if X%board_size == 0 :
      print("")
      print(("--+" * (board_size - 1)), end="")
      print("--")
    else:
      print("|", end="")
    X = X + 1
  turn = turn + 1
  Symbol_1, Symbol_2 = Symbol_2, Symbol_1
  print("You are user " + Symbol_1 + ".")
  user_input = input("Please pick a slot on the game board (using numbers 1 - " + str(squared_input) + "): ")
  a_list[int(user_input) - 1] = Symbol_1
```

Comment: Hi Jonny, Would it be possible to post the code you have so far into your question post above? (Instead of as a link? :)

Comment: Analyzing each number, you can print a blank space when numbers are of only 1 digit. That way, every number will occupy 2 spaces and alignment issue will be fixed. Another recommendation is provide a little more gap so everything looks nice and well spaced.

Comment: hi Jonny, your facing alignment issues bcz all the numbers are in different orders. Maintaining same order depends on board_size will solve your problem.

`1. Single digit numbers its better for use: 01,02,03 ... 09,10,11...`
`2. If its a big number above 3 digits, we can  001,002 ....009,010,...100,101..`

Answer (score 0):

The zeros come from your call to `zfill` which explicitly pads a string with 0 to a requested size. You call `zfill(2)` with a string that contains a single character. So the function pads that to length two by adding a `0`.

To pad with blanks you can for example use the `format()` function or just something like

```
'%2d' % a_list[X-1]
```

which will pad each number to length 2 from the left with blanks, or

```
'%-2d' % a_list[X-1]
```

which will pad each number to length 2 from the right with blanks.